# Restore a layout

Tags: wp-admin

We have been working on a page and realized that one section suddenly disappeared.
we are not sure how and I can't seem to be able to restore/find a backup.

Could you please help?
Thank you!

Comment: I'm afraid it's hard to troubleshoot this sort of thing without direct access to the site. Are you using Classic Editor, Block Editor, or a page builder? And have you switched between those recently? Has Core or any of your main plugins or theme been updated recently?